# Get union type of object keys when object property is initialized with an empty array

Tags: typescript, types, typing, type-alias

Let's say we have an object and an array:

Object:

```
const obj = {
  property1: [],
  property2: [],
}
```

Array:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3]
```

First of all, I would like to get the keys of the object as a type. We can achieve it by doing this:

```
type ObjectKeys = keyof typeof obj // <-- "property1" | "property2"
```

It works as expected. Now I want to assign the array to the first property of the object, but there is an error:

```
obj.property1 = arr // <-- Error: Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
```

My understanding is that this is because we initialized `obj` with empty arrays, so TypeScript doesn't know what the type of those arrays will be. To solve this problem, I tried to add typing to the object using `Record` utility:

```
type Obj = Record<string, number[]>

const obj: Obj = {
  property1: [],
  property2: [],
}
```

This works, but now there's another problem - we lost typing for the object keys:

```
type ObjectKeys = keyof typeof obj // <-- string
```

My question is, how should `obj` be typed so that TypeScript knows that `property1` will be an array of numbers, and at the same time I should be able to extract the object key as union type? I know that we can type all object properties directly rather than using the `Record` utility:

```
type Obj = {
  property1: number[],
  property2: number[]
}
```

But the problem is that we don't know how many and what properties will `obj` contain (`property1` or `property2` can be called anything else). The only thing we know is that the type of these properties will be `number[]`.

Is there any way to achieve the described behavior?

Comment: You could use a type assertion  `as number[]` for each array or use a do-nothing function to initialize `obj` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NB5Gdw). Not sure if this really is a satisfying solution though :/

Comment: I agree; it would have been nice if [the `satisfies` operator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-rc/#satisfies) had fixed this, but it doesn't (see "the empty array problem" in [ms/TS#47920](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920)).  I think the generic identity helper function is the right approach.  Maybe @TobiasS. should write up an answer?